# How to use recursion within a ES6 promise?

Tags: javascript, recursion, es6-promise, axios

I want to check if a post with a newly set id already exists using an axios get request. (I am doing this on the front-end because I don't control the back-end)

However I am not sure how to combine the recursion I want for when a posts with that id already exists and the promise it is in.

This is what I got so far:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import uuidv4 from 'uuid/v4';

export function newPost(post) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    getUniqueId.then((id) => {
      // post new post with unique id
      // dispatch({ type: NEW_POST_FULFILLED, payload: err });
    }).catch((err) => {
      dispatch({ type: NEW_POST_FAILED, payload: err });
    })
  }
}

const getUniqueId = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  checkUniqueId(resolve, reject, uuidv4())
});

const checkUniqueId = (resolve, reject, id) => {
  axios
    .get(`${api}/posts/${id}`, { headers })
    .then((resp) => checkUniqueId(resolve, reject, uuidv4()))
    .catch((err) => {
      if(err.response.status === 500) {
        resolve(id);
      } else {
        reject(err);
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why do you need recursion here ? If you're checking for a single post whether it exists or not than you don't need recursion. In the other hand if you're willing to generate as much ID's as you need for an inexistent post than that isa different case.

Comment: What is not working in your code..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues:

- `getUniqueId` should be a function, since you would want to get a new id every time `newPost` is called.
- You should not use the [promise constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it): don't create a new promise, but instead just return the promise itself, or `throw` when you need to reject.

Here is the corrected code:

```
export function newPost(post) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        // Call as function!
        getUniqueId().then((id) => {
            // post new post with unique id
            // dispatch({ type: NEW_POST_FULFILLED, payload: err });
        }).catch((err) => {
            dispatch({ type: NEW_POST_FAILED, payload: err });
        })
    }
}

// Define as function, and just return the promise from `checkUniqueId`
const getUniqueId = _ => checkUniqueId(uuidv4());

const checkUniqueId = (id) => {
    // return the promise!
    return axios
        .get(`${api}/posts/${id}`, { headers })
        .then((resp) => checkUniqueId(uuidv4()))
        .catch((err) => {
            if (err.response.status === 500) {
                return id;
            } else {
                throw err; // throw the error to cascade it through the chain
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how this could work:

```js
var i = 0;

function newPost() {
  getUniqueId().then(function(id) {
    console.log('got it: ' + id);
  });
}

function getUniqueId() {
  return checkUniqueId(i).catch(function() {
    console.log('id ' + i + ' is already in use');
    i++;
    return getUniqueId();
  });
}

function checkUniqueId(id) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (i < 2) {
      reject();
    } else {
      resolve(id);
    }
  });
}

newPost();
```

I rewrote it a bit to be able to test and understand it myself, so hopefully you're able to transform this back :).